# Laravel relation one to many get results joined

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm kinda lost one this one, I really can't find the problem, I have been watching a lot of questions all over the web but still can't seem to put this working properly.

I have two tables, the tabelaAngaricao table and the tabelaFotos table with a relationship of one-to-many, meaning that a tabelaAngariacao can have many tabelaFotos, and tabelaFotos as a angariacaoid(foreign key) so my tabelaAngariacao model is:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\TabelaFotos;

class TabelaAngariacao extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tabelaAngariacao'; 
    public function TabelaFotos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TabelaFotos::class, 'angariacaoid');
    }
}
```

and my tabelaFotos model is:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\TabelaAngariacao;

class TabelaFotos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tabelaFotos'; 

    public function TabelaAngariacao()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\TabelaAngariacao');
    }
}
```

What I want is to **get all results joined by the angariacaoid**, so in my controller I have:

```
public function index()
    {

        $results = DB::table('tabelaAngariacao')
            ->leftJoin('tabelaFotos', 'tabelaAngariacao.id', '=', 'tabelaFotos.angariacaoid')
            ->select('tabelaAngariacao.*')
            ->get();

    }
```

Could someone help me on finding the problem? What is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check without using this line `->select('tabelaAngariacao.*')`

Comment: Oh Man!!!!, that was exactly the problem...thank you so much Ayaz...by the way, could you tell me, how would the query be to get only some fields from my tabelaFotos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to add `select`. Try following

```
$results = DB::table('tabelaAngariacao')
->leftJoin('tabelaFotos', 'tabelaAngariacao.id', '=', 'tabelaFotos.angariacaoid')
->get();
```

The above script will give you columns from both tables.

Answer (score 1):

And probably you don't need to use `DB::table`, you can use Eloquent Queries instead, since you've defined your relationsips

You can try it by doing this.

`$results = TabelaFotos::with('TabelaAngariacao')->get();`

Here is how it works

```
$results = ModelName::with('relationship_in_model_name')->get();
```

Hope it works

Comment: Thanks for answering too Gabriel, but this doesn´t give me all the results: $records = TabelaAngariacao::with('TabelaFotos')->get();